# Parsing XML node's attribute with prefixes - XSTREAM/JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm using StaxDriver with XStream and trying to parse this XML:

```
<cad:MyObj xmlns:cad="namespace" cad:testeId="873" >
  <cad:node1>value node 1</cad:node1>
</cad:MyObj>
```

into an object.

I can parse node1 with the prefix but I don't know how to configure XStream with Stax to use the prefix `cad` with atributes (`testeId`).

Here's my conf:

```
QNameMap qnameMap = new QNameMap(); 
            qnameMap.setDefaultPrefix("cad");
            qnameMap.setDefaultNamespace("namespace");
            StaxDriver stax = new StaxDriver(qnameMap);
            stax.getInputFactory().setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
            stax.setRepairingNamespace(true);
            stax.setQnameMap(qnameMap);
            xstream = new XStream(stax); 
            xstream.alias("MyObj", MyObj.class);
            xstream.useAttributeFor(MyObj.class, "testeId");
```

I've tried to "cheat" with this:

```
xstream.aliasField("cad:testeId", ProdutoVersao.class, "testeId");
```

but didn't work =/

Hope someone know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I think there is no solution for this using XStream.

I've changed to JAXB with a namespace prefix mapper:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

```
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
ProdutoVersaoPrefixMapper mapper = new ProdutoVersaoPrefixMapper();
m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper);
```

With this code the node and his attributes get the prefix.